# How to cache UIImage converted from CIImage

Tags: ios, performance, uicollectionview, uiimage, core-image

In an iOS app, I want to display `CIImage` images (coming from CIFilter's) in a `UICollectionView` but performance is very poor because `CIImage` is refreshed each time a new cell appears.
So I wanted to cache all filtered images by setting them in an `UIImage` and storing this `UIImage`. However it seems `UIImage` will only calculate the filtered image once displayed.
I tried using `CGImage`, `NSData`... but nothing helped.

What's the best way to force calculation of `CIImages` and cache the image output ?

```
// Generation of cached images:
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    CIFilter *filteredimage=<output of function>
    CIImage *img=filteredimage.outputImage;
    UIImage *uImg=[UIImage imageWithCIImage:img];
    [filterPreviews addObject:uImg];
}

// Reuse of cached images in the cell
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    colorFilterCollectionViewCell *cell = (colorFilterCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.filterPreview.image=[filterPreviews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what is the use case you are trying to achieve in the app, maybe you want to dynamically show some filters preview and my solution might be not good but you can try using [writePNGRepresentation(of:to:format:colorSpace:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/2866197-writepngrepresentation)

Comment: I have indeed a main picture and a collection view of color filters to be applied on the picture.And each time I scroll the collectionview, cells need to be updated with filters which is lagging. I could indeed try to save the image, but am sure there are more efficient ways.

Comment: The idea is that if this is just a preview if the filter that the user will get as an output if they select I would expect the the image that you present on the collection view to be pre-rendered UIImage provided from you view model for example and cached. Once rendered you should not re-render unless the user selects another image.

Comment: That's exactly what I try to achieve, but don't know how to pre-render UIImage. [UIImage imageWithCIImage:img]; does not prerender and will only be calculated with UIImage actually displayed.

Comment: Assuming you have 10 images to cache and are displaying 3 cells at a time, could you (a) create "placeholder" UIImages that are probably clear color, (b) render your thumbnails in a separate UIImageContext, forcing CoreImage output, and (c) cache the images in your array and refresh the table? You might even go the route of trying threading, but beyond UI - which has to run on the main thread, not much is happening on the CPU and CoreImage should manage threading on the GPU.